# C# VAR basic understanding

Tags: c#, var

Basically I have a function as below that allow user login when execute the application:

```
public void login(){
    //Call StoredProc get a list of records 
    //and add the results into a list<T> SPList

    var tempList = SPList.Where(x=>x.Status==1);
    int counter = tempList.Count();

    //What is the number of counter?
}
```

Now when user first run the application, `login` function will be executed and `tempList.Count()` is expected to be **2**.

When user run the same method `login()` again, the `tempList.Count()` is now becoming **4**??

**BUT**, if user kill the apps and restart it, `tempList.Count()` will then return **2** again?

**Isn't that keyword VAR will refresh and return 2 everytime? Why is it holding the old data and expanding instead of refreshing?**

Comment: `var` is a red herring, I suspect. Where/how is `SPList` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you don't understand what `var` does. With `var` the compiler tries to understand what type is returned from your method.

Your problem is that you keep a list in memory, where you add things, and thus the count will get updated. At restart, the list is empty again, so you will start with 0.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with 'var'.  Var is just a feature which allows you to not have to type the type when declaring a variable.

It has more to do with the inner-workings of LINQ.   You should understand that your variable tempList is not holding a List or Collection, but rather an expression.
Each time you do an operation on 'tempList' (like calling Count() or iterating over it), the expression will be evaluated again.

this:

```
var tempList = SPList.Where(x=>x.Status==1);
int counter = tempList.Count();
```

will behave totally different than this:

```
var tempList = SPList.Where(x=>x.Status==1).ToList();
int counter = tempList.Count();
```

In the second code-sample, the variable 'tempList' really contains a List, whereas in the first code-sample, the variable tempList contains an expression.

When you add a new object to `SPList`, and call Count() on tempList again, the new item will be included in the count in the first code-example, whereas in the second code-sample it will not be included.  (Since in the 2nd sample, tempList is now a separete list, whereas in the first sample, the expression that counts the items in SPList is executed again).

Comment: `Count()` should return consistent results from either variant you show, if the contents of `SPList` remain the same, so I disagree with your "will behave totally different" - in this case, and using just `Count`, the results should be identical.

Comment: This answer is only true if performed with an `IQueryable` collection. Normal LINQ isn't deferred. Unless I misunderstand what you mean..